# How can I determine what version SQL Server Compact a table is?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sql-server-ce, windows-ce, server-explorer

I have some .SDF tables that are created in a Windows CE app (access table data is passed from a server app, and this is converted into SQL Server Compact records/tables).

I want to look inside them from my desktop machine in Visual Studio 2010. But attempting to create a new Data Connection in the Server Explorer, selecting either of the two "Microsoft SQL Server Compact" Data sources (3.5 and 4.0) fails.

When I choose 3.5 and then "Test Connection," it tells me:

> This is not a valid SQL Server Compact Database file or this file version is not supported by current SQL Server Compact Engine.

When I choose 4.0 and then "Test Connection," it tells me:

> Incompatible Database Version. If this was a compatible file, run repair. For other cases refer to documentation. [ Db version = 0, Requested version = 0,File name = MyRecalcitrantTable.SDF

Is there a way to make a connection to these tables so I can query them to see what they contain? How can I determine which version they were created with (apparently prior to 3.5) so that I can possibly use an earlier version of VS to view them (or some other tool?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use my SQL Server Compact Toolbox VS extension, it has a Detect file version feature, but they are probably version 2.0 files, and can only be opened on a Windows ce device (or emulator)

Comment: Would such an emulator be available from VS 200X?

Comment: You must install the 2.0 Query emulator on the device, or install VS.NET 2003 which has a Pocket PC emulator